# Date Calculation with Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, formatting, auto-increment

I am having problem to calculating the date in js.  I have calendar picker in my form to pick a start date in the format of mm/dd/yy.  With that start date value, I want to insert the incremental date into the rows up to 2 wks.

Plz, can anyone help me on this?  thank you.

Danny

Comment: Can you show us some code so we don't have to guess at what you're doing.

Comment: You'll need to show us the code you've attempted, so we can see the problem.  Perhaps use something like http://jsfiddle.net/ to create a sample

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is what you want but.

```
var date = new Date(year, month, day ); 
date = date.setDate( date.getDate() + 14 ); // add 14 days to the date
```